# Display Chat widget in another react app component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundle, chatbot

I created a chatbot widget application in react js. I wanted to show the chatbot widget in my dashboard application as well.
So in the dashboard react application, I made changes as given below and the chatbot widget was also showing and working fine.

[image]

Note: index file in the script tag is a bundled js file of the chatbot widget application.

But, I want to display the chatbot widget on particular pages like the landing page only. But making changes in the index.html file in the public folder renders the widget on every page.

I tried conditional statements in the script tag as shown below,

[image]

But we must reload and refresh the page to see the changes. I don't want to reload/refresh the page every time we navigate to a different URL.

Please help me to resolve this issue.